# WebLogic crashes

Tags: liferay, weblogic, hsqldb

I am running Liferay 6.2 on WebLogic 12c server.

Out of nowhere it just stopped working.

This is the last thing I see before it throws a flurry of exceptions

```
<Jan 10, 2014 2:53:28 PM EST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log fi
le C:\Oracle_2\Middleware\user_projects\domains\liferay\servers\AdminServer\logs
\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. Th
is can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.>
<Jan 10, 2014 2:53:28 PM EST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log fi
le has been rotated to C:\Oracle_2\Middleware\user_projects\domains\liferay\serv
ers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log00369. Log messages will continue to be logg
ed in C:\Oracle_2\Middleware\user_projects\domains\liferay\servers\AdminServer\l
ogs\AdminServer.log.>
```

The errors are shown here http://www.pastebin.ca/2532946

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the log files (see below excerpt of your log file), Liferay is not able to either get a handle to the HSQL database or the HSQL db might be corrupted when you updated it.

```
13:11:16,769 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->uArzPQ2m]-HelperThread-#4][BasicResourcePool:1851] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@933b16 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception:
```

java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 15 unexpected token: AVG

So you need to answer below questions:

- Did you use any Client tool to make changes to your HSQL db?

  - If yes, did you close the connection to HSQL database before starting Liferay?

    - If not, Liferay won't be able to acquire lock on your db and fail to start.
  - If not, did you make DB changes directly in the HSQL db file?

    - This is NOT Recommended. Rollback your changes and try to use HSQL client to make your db changes

HTH!

P.S. Is this issue duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052236/weblogic-wont-start. If so, please delete that one.

Comment: I did indeed use SquirrelSQL to make changes in my database, and was not aware of the HSQL client. Thank you very much Rushikesh!

Comment: Yeah, HSQL doesn't allow multiple processes accessing it at the same time. So if you connected to the db using Squirrel (or any DB client), that will acquire the lock on the DB. So Liferay won't be able to acquire it, and will eventually crash.

Comment: Thanks again. Might you know anything about Liferay on a Dev server? I'm having issues with creating/saving content.